# How to find standard deviation of a seemingly qualitative data set?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

My data set is the Wins of a baseball team. They have 8 wins, 5 losses, and 1 tie. A tie is counted as 1/2 of a win, so there are 8.5 wins. The probability of the team winning based on this data is then 8.5/14, or 0.607. How would I find the standard deviation of the number of wins? I feel like I'm overthinking this but I'm not sure what to use for my x values would be in this instance

Comment: You have to decide how you are modeling the situation.  You might, for instance, assume that each game is an independent event with success probability $.607$ in which case you could get the standard deviation from the resulting binomial distribution.  There's nothing in the data that tells you that this model is correct, however.  Doesn't even seem terribly likely...as, presumably, the probability of winning a single game depends on the opponent and other factors.

Comment: To be clear:  the modeling part is not a math question. Or, at least not exclusively a math problem.   You'd need a lot more data to be able to test whatever modeling assumption you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you limit this to a purely academic binomial type problem, then the formula for standard deviation is:

$\sigma_x = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$

$\sigma_x = \sqrt{14(.607)(.393)}$

$\sigma_x  = 1.8275$